# Configuring Bonding of Two 10Gb NICs Using Netplan

Tags: networking

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS and I want to bond two 10Gb NICs using LACP up to a Cisco 3850 switch....this is the configuration I'm using but it is not working....I'm editing the YAML file within Netplan:

YAML File Configuration

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  bonds:
    bond0:
      interfaces:
        - ens1f0
        - ens1f1
      addresses: [192.168.1.49/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      nameservers:
         addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
      parameters:
        mode: 802.3ad
        lacp-rate: fast
        primary: ens1f0
        mii-monitor-interval: 100
```

Answer (score 5):

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens1f0:
      dhcp4: no
    ens1f1:
      dhcp4: no
  bonds:
    bond0:
      interfaces: [ens1f0, ens1f1]
      addresses: [192.168.1.49/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      nameservers:
         addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
      parameters:
        mode: 802.3ad
        lacp-rate: fast
        primary: ens1f0
        mii-monitor-interval: 100
```

Use this please

Comment: Alpy...thank you very much...your reply back with a NIC bonding configuration recommendation works great...thank you again

Comment: glad it did... please mark the answer as valid :) Thx